# how to create user that have same permission as root in CentOS 7?

Tags: root, useradd

how to create user that have same permission as **root** in CentOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create another user with the same permissions as root. Root is a system user with special privileges. The privileges of root come from the user ID 0, not from a flag on the account or from the name “root” (that's just a convention, but a universally followed convention, so if you use a different name you'll break a lot of software and sysadmins).

You can have as many **users with administrative privileges** as you want. They won't be called root or have user ID 0, they're just normal accounts with the **privilege to execute commands as root**. The most common way to give an account administrative privileges is to configure [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to allow them to run commands as root. Such accounts are called “sudoers”. Then, to run a command that requires administrative privileges, you run `sudo commandname argument…`.

Comment: I would say that you are proposing to give a regular user a possibility to escalate privileges, not to have same permissions as root. But I think that OP has to be more specific what exactly he wants to achieve.

Comment: @Kalavan I proposed to give a regular user a possibility to escalate privileges because that's the way it's done. Interpreting the request literally (as in, having processes running as a user that is not root but that have all the privileges of the root user) is impossible because some privileges are tied to the uid value. The actual purpose of having root privileges is to be able to perform actions with root privileges, and sudo is the most common way to do that.

Comment: And with this comment I would say it is full answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
useradd -u 0 --non-unique yourrootuser
```

You also might want to add it to root group and specify any other switches to create a user you want. User id equal to 0 is most important to achieve your goal.

Comment: This doesn't create a user with the same permission as root, it creates another name and password for the same user. This is an important distinction.

Comment: Gilles, yes, this creates another user with the same User ID. And all is special about root is it's id :)

Answer (score -2):

issue `usermod -aG wheel <username>`

This will add your user into group `wheel` which have same permissions as root.

Comment: This is wrong. root has superuser permissions. A non-root user being in the wheel group **does not** have superuser permissions.